# Selenium WebDriver is not clicking on first button

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, browser-automation

I have a List containing 5 'Buy' buttons. Selenium WebDriver is not  clicking the first 'Buy' button but clicks the remaining 4 just fine. Ran a println and it shows all 5 buy buttons being found by WebDriver.

I have tried switching the order of buttons in the List, I have attempted to debug it,  I have included explicit wait also but nothing is helping. Anyone has any clues?

My code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allProductsOnsite.size(); i ++) {
        //System.out.println(allProductsOnsite.get(i).getText());
        if (prodsToBuy.contains(allProductsOnsite.get(i).getText())) {
            System.out.println("Found -------" + allProductsOnsite.get(i).getText() );
            WebDriverWait wt = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
            wt.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(allProductsOnsite));

            allBuyButtons.get(i).click();
        }
}
```

Comment: You're checking the WebElements in `allProductsOnsite`, but you're not checking the WebElements in `allBuyButtons`.  So you're println is not showing that all 5 buttons have been found, but rather that 5 products have been found.  It could be that the first product loaded, but it's button didn't load before Selenium looked for all the buttons.

Try checking each element in `allBuyButtons`, and give us an update with what you find.

Comment: Thank you for helping me  TJamesBoone,
I followed what you have advised and did a println on allBuyButtons and it gives me the expected correct number of butttons on the page which makes me think that since all expected buttons are visible, webdriver should be able to click on them but it's still not clicking on the first button.

Comment: provide more information like: how are you finding all buttons, html snippet (or link to web page)

Comment: *As an experiment* (this is not something you ever want to do in serious code), put a Thread.sleep(3000) right before your for loop and run your code.

**If it works**, then we'll know that `visibilityOfAllElements()` is not a sufficient condition for the first button to be clickable.

**If it still doesn't work**, then we'll know that the problem is not related to not waiting long enough.

Comment: Is your first button displayed on the second screen so webdriver has to scroll down before clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to click using JavascriptExecutor

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginButton']/div"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Also use some wait if needed before this code

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Good idea, I will try this also and let you know the results.

Comment: Yes it worked out fine with the executor. Thank you.